# Regarding an equivalence realtion on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying equivalence relations and came upon this problem:

Let $X=\mathbb Z \times  \mathbb Z$ where $\mathbb Z$ denotes the integers,  and $(x_1,y_1)\sim (x_2,y_2)\iff  x_1y_1=x_2y_2$

I had to prove that it was an equivalence relation. Which I can do.

My question is,
are the elements of this relation just the ordered pairs themselves?
Eg  $(1,3)=(1,3)$ reflexive, symmetric, transitive.

Comment: Yes; the relation is defined on *pairs*: $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: You have asked a few questions now, it would be easier to read them if you typed them using mathjax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: And yes, it is reflexive: $(x,y) \sim (x,y)$ because $xy=xy$ (assuming that the formula defining the rel is correct...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a set $X$ is a subset $R^{\sim} \subseteq X \times X$ such that

- For all $x \in X$, $(x, x) \in R^{\sim}$.
- For all $x, y \in X$, if $(x,y) \in R^{\sim}$, then $(y, x) \in R^{\sim}$.
- For all $x, y, z \in X$, if $(x,y) \in R^{\sim}$ and $(y,z) \in R^{\sim}$, then $(x, z) \in R^{\sim}.$

So in our case, the relation $\sim$ is indeed defined on pairs (i.e. on elements of $X = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$), but the elements of this equivalence relation $R^{\sim}$ are elements from $X \times X = (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z)\times (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z)$, i.e. pairs $(a,b)$ where each of $a$ and $b$ are pairs themselves (more precisely they are elements from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$).